# Why C standard does not define the behavior of fflush(stdin)?

Tags: c

I understand that `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behavior, because `fflush` is only defined for output buffers.

But **why?** Is there any historical reasons for not defining `fflush` for input buffers?

C++ provides a way to clear standard input buffer, `cin.clear()`, and I don't understand why it is left undefined in C standard.

Comment: Your desired behavior would be for `fflush(stdin)` to throw away the input buffer? `fflush` on output buffers has almost the opposite meaning; yes, the buffer is cleared, but only because the data in it has been flushed to the OS for safe storage, it's not thrown away. Having `fflush(stdin)` mean "throw away whatever is in the buffer" would be... confusing, especially on pipes/sockets. It wouldn't even have a particularly useful meaning; the input buffer isn't the same as whatever is sitting on the OS input handle, so it would never be clear exactly what you were throwing away.

Comment: Both the [linux man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) and the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) allow for calling on input streams.

Comment: It also looks like that language in the standard goes back to C89.

Comment: @dbush: Huh. It has never occurred to me to *try* doing that. And it's definitely not the same behavior for both (Linux throws away the buffer, Windows only throws away stuff pushed back in via `ungetc`, but otherwise keeps the buffer), so I don't think I'll be attempting that anytime soon. :-)

Comment: `cin.clear()` just clears `cin`'s error flags.  It doesn't flush anything.  The C equivalent would be `clearerr`.  Maybe you're thinking about `cin.ignore()`?  Even then, that's just a fancy `fread`.

Comment: The terminal/console you use already buffers input, you can't see anything until you press the Enter key.  Like teletypes used to work back in the 1970s.  fflush() can't clear the terminal buffer, so it usually does nothing.  YMMV.

Comment: The "fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard" in [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) is consistent with step 2 of a [strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace%2C_extend%2C_and_extinguish).  With C calling `fflush(stdin)` UB, it allows that extension without endorsing it.

Comment: @chux: If the worst thing Microsoft does with `fflush(stdin)` is make it undo the effects of `ungetc`, I don't think they'll be getting around to step 3 anytime soon. So little software uses `ungetc` at all that I'd struggle to come up with an example that also needs to undo it without knowing whether it has already happened.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The [linked doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx) also has the curious `// You must flush the input buffer before using gets.)`.  For me, that wrong "must" advice leads a learner into using UB, à la MS, and is a _worst thing_.  Better to code to standards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why **should** `fflush(stdin)` be defined?  From the program's perspective, buffering is transparent, so `fflush(stdin)` could discard nothing, or it could consume and discard the entire input data stream. Unlike an output stream, where the program controls what's been emitted, the program has no knowledge of what's in an input buffer.

The result of `fflush(stdin)` is unclear at best - there's no clear way to say what it will do.  Just try it on an input stream that isn't a terminal in line-buffered mode on a platform that does specify its behavior.  Then change the size of the buffer and try it again.  You'll likely get completely different results in what data you subsequently read.

Comment: `Just try it on an input stream that isn't a terminal in line-buffered mode on a platform that does specify its behavior. Then change the size of the buffer and try again.` I cannot figure out what to do to. What should I do to test the behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to popular belief, it is not clear what `fflush(stdin)` should do:

- Some programmers seem to assume it should discard any pending input from the terminal, and it does that on some systems.
- Others would expect it to just discard bytes pushed back via `ungetc()` and indeed some systems implement it this way.
- Yet others would expect something else, and some implementations have another behavior, for example reading and discarding all available input, including from regular files.

When a function has been implemented in different incompatible ways on various widely available historical platforms, the rationale of the C Standard seems to not try and specify anything as it would make many existing platforms non-conforming. Hence `fflush(stdin)` is just specified as having *undefined behavior*.

Note that the most commonly expected semantics are easy to implement as a function:

```
/* discard the rest of a line of pending input,
 * return EOF at end of file.
 */
int flushline(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}
```